# Import one class in another within same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder named 'container' which have two classes:

1. `VisitorPage.py`
2. `TestMethods.py`
3. `__init__.py`

I want to import 'VisitorPage' in TestMethods class so I can use its methods.

I have tried following, but not succeeded yet.

```
from .containers import VisitorPage
```

Error:

```
from .containers import VisitorPage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests.containers.containers'
```

Second scenario:

```
from containers import VisitorPage
```

Error

```
from containers import VisitorPage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'containers'
```

Scenario 3:

```
import containers.VisitorPage
```

Error:

```
import containers.VisitorPage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'containers'
```

Can someone please let me know the correct way to do it. Thanks

Comment: Wherever you're running your code, try printing the path via `import sys; print(sys.path)`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you the problem. Both `VisitorPage` and `TestMethods` are in the folder `containers`. Using `.` refers to the current module. Using `.containers` means you are searching for a module `containers` within `containers`.

My guess is your project structure is

```
containers/
|- VisitorPage.py
|- TestMethods.py
```

If that is the case, then inside `TestMethods.py`, just

```
import VisitorPage
```

Otherwise, you need to put `containers` in a directory so that your directory structure is

```
project/    
    |-containers/
         |- VisitorPage.py
         |- TestMethods.py
```

where `project` is the root directory.

So inside `TestMethods.py`, you import `VisitorPage` using relative import

```
from . import VisitorPage
```

or if you want to use absolute import

```
from containers import VisitorPage
```